# Comparing columns in excel and finding errors

Tags: excel

I have a large csv file (over 5 million rows) - I need to compare two columns to check that the number in one column matches the description in the second column.  For example in the simplified picture - I have an ID number which corresponds to a vessel type - I need to make sure this match - as when I do analysis on the unique values it is obviously double counting where the vessel type is wrong.

So I need to identify the errors and replace them with the correct value.

Thanks

[image]

looking manually would take me days - so need a formula or tool to automate.

Comment: *I have a large csv file (over 5 million rows)* If you really got 5 million of rows then Excel is not the right tool because it can handle around 1 million rows as far as i know.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Microsoft-365 has `1048576` rows.

Comment: @Harun24hr Exactly, that's why I said Excel is not the right tool to handle 5 million records (that's what OP said)

Comment: Then again, you don't actually need to open the file in Excel. You could read the contents with VBA, do the magic and just save it again.

Comment: @Andreas Do you have a VBA script that could do this?  I'm working with the data mainly in Arc Pro (GIS) but need to find a way to do the corrections.

Comment: how do you know which description is correct, for example with ID 1000 - should Cargo be correct or Fishing?

Comment: @rodro that's not too much of an issue - if I can at least just identify which ones have errors - I can go through them to double check and correct - in most cases - it's just that they've been given the generic name "ship" so - would just need to change it to "cargo ship"

Comment: someone did post a formula that worked perfectly - but now it's gone - if you can paste it back that would be very helpful!

Comment: This is the formula which i had posted for Conditional formatting : `=COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,"<>"&B2)<>0`

Comment: Should I post it as an answer?